# Get the date of the next week-day (skipping weekends) for displaying data in HTML

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have the following Code:

```
Public Shared Function DPLoadData() As String
    Dim s As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder("<head><meta http-equiv=""content-type"" content=""text/html;charset=utf-8"" /><META HTTP-EQUIV=""REFRESH"" CONTENT=""900"">")
    s.Append("<style type=""text/css"" media=""all""> body{font-family: Arial;}h4{font-size: 10pt;font-weight: bold;white-space: nowrap;margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;}")
    s.Append("th{font-size: 9pt;font-weight: normal;text-align: center;white-space: nowrap;}td{font-size: 9pt;}.content td{border: solid 1px #dadada;}")
    s.Append(".content th {border: solid 1px #dadada;background-image: url(""tbl_header_row_bg.gif""); background-repeat: repeat-x; white-space: nowrap;}</style></head>")
    s.Append("<h3>" & "Daily Plan" & "</h3>")
    Dim strCurrDay As String = ""
    s.Append("<h5>" & strCurrDay & "</h5>")

    Dim CurrDateFirstDay As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, Now)
    strCurrDay = FormatDateTime(CurrDateFirstDay, DateFormat.LongDate)

    s.Append("<h5>" & strCurrDay & "</h5>")
    s.Append(LoadDataGroupByDate(CurrDateFirstDay))
    Return s.ToString()
End Function
```

The function generates an HTML file with a table and fills it with bookings. Currently, the HTML file displays the bookings of tomorrow (e.g. if today is Monday, it displays the bookings for Tuesday). So far so good. What I want is that if today is Friday, the HTML File should display the bookings for Monday, not Saturday. Is that possible?

My Solution:

```
        If value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday Then

            Dim CurrDateFirstDay As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 3, Now)

            strCurrDay = FormatDateTime(CurrDateFirstDay, DateFormat.LongDate)
            s.Append("<h5>" & strCurrDay & "</h5>")
            s.Append(LoadDataGroupByDate(CurrDateFirstDay))
        Else
            Dim CurrDateFirstDay As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, Now)

            strCurrDay = FormatDateTime(CurrDateFirstDay, DateFormat.LongDate)
            s.Append("<h5>" & strCurrDay & "</h5>")
            s.Append(LoadDataGroupByDate(CurrDateFirstDay))

        End If
```

Comment: I removed your second question about how to automatically generate the file at 5:00pm every day.  That's an entirely separate question, so you should ask it separately rather than combining both into one post.

Comment: ok, i will ask it separately. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a method like this:

```
Public Function GetNextWeekDay() As Date
    Dim value As Date = Date.Now
    Do
        value = value.AddDays(1)
    Loop While (value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday) Or (value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    Return value
End Function
```

Then you can set your variable like this:

```
Dim CurrDateFirstDay As Date = GetNextWeekDay()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. It works like charm. Your solution is more efficient but nn the meantime i wrote something, can you have a look at it and tell me if that would work also? I updated my Question

Comment: Yes, your updated question also looks like a good alternative.  It would be minutely more efficient by avoiding the loop, but it doesn't account for the current day being a saturday or a sunday.